# How to force "dynamic" behavior in a LINQ expression with DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net

Let's assume I have a class `D` that derives from `DynamicObject`. The intention is for `D` to wrap some object in a way to expose more properties than originally available in a wrapped object.

Let's also assume that the following expression compiles and executes and the variable value is `1` as expected.

```
var age = (int)((dynamic)new D(new Person{Age = 45})).Age;
```

Now, if I try to build an expression that uses `D` instead of `Person` directly like so:

```
var p = Expression.Parameter(typeof(D), "p");
var e = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda(new[] { p }, null, "p.Age > 45");
```

I get a nice `ParseException` telling me that "No property or field 'Age' exists in type 'D'". Substituting `typeof(D)` with `typeof(Person)` works.

How can I build an expression that treats `p` as `dynamic`? I have tried lots of things and I ended up using `System.Linq.Dynamic` from NuGet but still no luck.

EDIT: Here are the classes used.
EDIT: I have found a solution using `DynamicExpression.CreateClass()` but I am not too happy as it effectively duplicates my object which can sometimes have deep hierarchy. Also, this is highly inefficient if the expression is only touching one property.

```
public class D : DynamicObject
{
    Person _p;

    public D(Person p)
    {
        _p = p;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return new [] {"Age"};
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        var name = binder.Name;
        if (name == "Age")
        {
            result = _p.Age;
            return true;
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}

class Person
{
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Can you add D and Person implementation?

Comment: Edited the question. This is of course an oversimplification but serves the demonstration purpose.

Comment: https://github.com/kahanu/System.Linq.Dynamic/issues/66

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer updated as original(stroke out) proved to be irrelevant.**

I did another research and probably found solution to your problem. Your question lacking more context, but I guess it will work for you.

**Solution**

First thing to do to make dynamic behavior work is to implement `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider` interface in class(es).  This interface represents dynamic object and has single method `GetMetaObject` which return `DynamicMetaObject`. In this case PersonMetaObject class.

```
public sealed class Person : IDynamicMetaObjectProvider {
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }

    public int GetAge() {
        return DateTime.Today.Year - BirthDate.Year;
    }

    DynamicMetaObject IDynamicMetaObjectProvider.GetMetaObject(Expression parameter) {
        return new PersonMetaObject(parameter, this);
    }
}
```

Now you have to implement overrides to `PersonMetaObject` class to allow custom runtime behavior. (Read as fun part)

```
internal class PersonMetaObject : DynamicMetaObject {
    private TypeInfo _typeInfo = typeof(Person).GetTypeInfo();

    public PersonMetaObject(Expression parameter, Person value)
        : base(parameter, BindingRestrictions.Empty, value) { }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder) {
        Expression self = GetSelfExpression();

        string propertyName = binder.Name;

        return BindGetInternal(self, propertyName);
    }

    public override DynamicMetaObject BindGetIndex(GetIndexBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject[] indexes) {
        Expression self = GetSelfExpression();

        string propertyName = indexes.First().Value.ToString();

        return BindGetInternal(self, propertyName);
    }

    private DynamicMetaObject BindGetInternal(Expression self, string propertyName) {
        switch (propertyName) {
            // Dynamic value computed in runtime
            case "FullName": {
                // Get FirstName property
                Expression firstName = Expression.Property(self, nameof(Person.FirstName));
                // Get LastName property
                Expression lastName = Expression.Property(self, nameof(Person.LastName));
                // Create constant containing space character
                Expression space = Expression.Constant(" ");


                Expression stringArray = Expression.NewArrayInit(typeof(string), firstName, lastName);

                Expression fullName = Expression.Call(null, typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(String.Join), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string[]) }), space, stringArray);

                // Create and return dynamic object metadata
                return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.Convert(fullName, typeof(object)), BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
            }
            // Defined method invoked
            case "Age": {
                // Get method info using type reflection
                MethodInfo getAge = _typeInfo.GetMethod(nameof(Person.GetAge));

                // Call reflected method
                Expression age = Expression.Call(self, getAge);

                // Create and return dynamic object metadata
                return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.Convert(age, typeof(object)), BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
            }
            // 
            default: {
                // if none case was hit we need to make sure to return declared property if exists
                if(_typeInfo.GetMembers().Any(m => m.Name == propertyName)) {
                    return new DynamicMetaObject(Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(self, propertyName), typeof(object)), BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
                }
                // If we get here something is wrong. To avoid exception we just return default value. But you would like to change it accordingly   
                // Create default object
                Expression @default = Expression.Default(typeof(object));

                // Create and return dynamic object metadata
                return new DynamicMetaObject(@default, BindingRestrictions.GetTypeRestriction(Expression, LimitType));
            }
        }
    }
    private Expression GetSelfExpression() {
        return Expression.Convert(Expression, LimitType);
    }
}
```

Last part is to write some logic to test it is working. In code below you can see there are two filters for IEnumerable using Func and two IQueryable. IQueryable is using programatically created expression.

```
class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            // Array of concrete types assigned to dynamic enumerable
            IEnumerable<dynamic> enumerable = new Person[] {
                new Person { BirthDate = new DateTime(1975, 8, 14), FirstName = "Alan",  LastName = "Smith" },
                new Person { BirthDate = new DateTime(2006, 1, 26), FirstName = "Elisa",  LastName = "Ridley" },
                new Person { BirthDate = new DateTime(1993, 12, 1), FirstName = "Randy",  LastName = "Knowles" },
                new Person { BirthDate = new DateTime(1946, 5, 8), FirstName = "Melissa",  LastName = "Fincher" }
            };

            IQueryable<dynamic> queryable = enumerable.AsQueryable();

            // Helper method to write data to console
            void Write(IEnumerable<dynamic> collection) {
                foreach (var item in collection) {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item.FullName} born {item.BirthDate.ToShortDateString()}");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            // Property access on dynamic object
            var youngsters = enumerable
                .Where(m => m.Age < 21);

            Console.WriteLine("Young people to test property acces:");
            Write(youngsters);

            // Index access on dynamic object
            var adults = enumerable
                .Where(m => m["Age"] > 20 && m["Age"] < 60);

            Console.WriteLine("Adult people to test index access:");
            Write(adults);

            // Composed lambda expression for queryable (be aware it is not going to work with EF)
            var seniors = queryable
                .Where(ExpressionFactory.PropertyGreaterThanPredicate("Age", 59));

            Console.WriteLine("Senior people to test property access lambda expression:");
            Write(seniors);

            // Composed lambda expression for queryable (be aware it is not going to work with EF)
            var some = queryable
                .Where(ExpressionFactory.IndexLessThanPredicate("Age", 60));

            Console.WriteLine("Some people to test index access lambda expression:");
            Write(some);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

`ExpressionFactory` implmentation is returning expression that contains dynamic expression responsible for runtime invocation and possibility to reach dynamic behavior. That was probably the issue you have been experiencing during your tries.

```
public static class ExpressionFactory {
        public static Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>> PropertyGreaterThanPredicate(string propertyName, int value){
            var constant = Expression.Constant(value);

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "m");

            // Creating binder to access class member
            var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, propertyName, typeof(Program), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });

            // Dynamic operation on the binder
            var dynamic = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), parameter);

            // Converting result to same type as value to compare
            var converted = Expression.Convert(dynamic, constant.Value.GetType());

            var predicate = Expression.GreaterThan(converted, constant);

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

            return lambda;
        }

        public static Expression<Func<dynamic, bool>> IndexLessThanPredicate(string indexName, int value) {
            var constant = Expression.Constant(value);

            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "m");

            // Creating binder to access indexer
            var binder = Binder.GetIndex(CSharpBinderFlags.None, typeof(Program), new CSharpArgumentInfo[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });

            // Dynamic operation on the binder
            var dynamic = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), parameter, Expression.Constant(indexName));

            // Converting result to same type as value to compare
            var converted = Expression.Convert(dynamic, constant.Value.GetType());

            var predicate = Expression.LessThan(converted, constant);

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<dynamic, bool>>(predicate, parameter);

            return lambda;
        }
    }
```

If you'll need full working sample you can find it in [GitHub repository](https://github.com/dropoutcoder/dynamic-type-linq-query).

In case there will be still issues, let me know. I'll try to help.

---

**Original answer**

<s>Only way how to make it work is to use generic method instead of passing parameter expression.</s>

```
namespace ConsoleApp2 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Dynamic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Dynamic;

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var dynamics = new D[] {
                new D(new Person { Age = 1 }),
                new D(new Person { Age = 50 }),
                new D(new Person { Age = 100 })
            };

            var first = dynamics[0].Age;

            var second = dynamics.Where(x => x.Age > 45);

            var filter = System.Linq.Dynamic.DynamicExpression.ParseLambda<D, bool>("Age > 45");

            var third = dynamics.Where(filter.Compile());
        }

        public class D : DynamicObject {
            Person _p;

            public D(Person p) {
                _p = p;
            }

            public Type Type => this._p.GetType();

            public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames() {
                return new[] { "Age" };
            }

            public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result) {
                var name = binder.Name;
                if (name == "Age") {
                    result = _p.Age;
                    return true;
                }

                result = null;
                return false;
            }

            public int Age => _p.Age;
        }

        public class Person {
            public int Age { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. But what you did is add a property Age on type D. That kind of defeats the purpose of D which is to wrap **any** type. Your solution is as good as using the type Person directly. The DynamicObject overrides are never called. As a matter of fact, if you comment out the Age property on type D, the code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @wpfwannabe: I hope this will be more helpful! Let me know in case you need some clarification.